# Nested use of `\pgfmathparse` for graph drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am using the `trees` `tikzlibrary` combined with some `pgfmath` commands to draw the ternary tree below:

[image]

To each vertex *u_i*, a certain *v_i* is associated.
So far, all of these *v_i*'s are labelled with *v_1*, but I would actually like the numbering to correspond to the *u_i*'s, so that *v_1* is adjacent to *u_1*, *v_2* is adjacent to *u_2*, and so on.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\d{3} %degree
\newlength{\leveldist} %level distance

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,circle,sibling angle=360/\d,draw]
\setlength{\leveldist}{10mm};
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5\leveldist]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=\leveldist,sibling angle=60]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=\leveldist,sibling angle=40]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[inner sep=0mm,minimum size=1mm,draw]
\node (Ac) {$u$} child foreach \A in {1,...,\d}
    { node (A\A) {} child foreach \B in {2,...,\d}              
        { node (A\A-\B) {$u_{\pgfmathparse{(\A-1)*2+\B-1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$} child foreach \C in {2,...,\d}
            { node (A\A-\B-\C) {\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(array({0,1,1,1,0,1},(\A-1)*2+\B-2)==\C-2,"$v_1$","")} \pgfmathresult} }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Here, using `"$v_{\pgfmathparse{(\A-1)*2+\B-1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$"`
instead of `"$v_1$"` to label the *v_i* (as it worked for the *u_i* in the line above) results in the compilation not terminating, probably because of the nested use of the two `\pgfmathparse` commands.

An alternative approach could be to introduce some variable to count the index instead of doing the computation in situ, but I was not able to make this work inside this structure.

Comment: Don't use the `minimal` documentclass. It is way too minimal for most purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - I have changed the documentclass to `article` (in my file) now. The problem persists, however.

Comment: Note that it is advised not to use `\tikzstyle` anymore, but instead use `\tikzset{<key-name>/.style={<stuff>}}` (this will most likely not fix your problem though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Description

As you already noticed, it seems to be impossible or at least difficult to use nested `\pgfmathparse`. The problem is, that `\pgfmathparse` is mainly used for arithmetic calculations and not for string building, but in this case a string must be concatenated with a calculated number. Therefore, I make use of another package `etoolbox` and it's command `\ifdefstring`.

##### Adaptations

- use `\ifdefstring` (from package `etoolbox`) to decide, depending on the result of `\pgfmathparse` to print `$v_i$` or nothing.
- use class `article` instead of `minimal`
- use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/123129)

##### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\d{3} %degree
\newlength{\leveldist} %level distance

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow cyclic,circle,sibling angle=360/\d,draw,
    level 1/.style={level distance=1.5\leveldist},
    level 2/.style={level distance=\leveldist,sibling angle=60},
    level 3/.style={level distance=\leveldist,sibling angle=40},
    every node/.style={inner sep=0mm,minimum size=1mm,draw},
]
    
    \setlength{\leveldist}{10mm};

    \node (Ac) {$u$} child foreach \A in {1,...,\d} {
        node (A\A) {} child foreach \B in {2,...,\d} {
            node (A\A-\B) {$u_{\pgfmathparse{(\A-1)*2+\B-1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$} child foreach \C in {2,...,\d} {
                node (A\A-\B-\C) {%
                    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(array({0,1,1,1,0,1},(\A-1)*2+\B-2)==\C-2, (\A-1)*2+\B-1, 0)}
                    \ifdefstring{\pgfmathresult}{0}{}{$v_{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$}
                }
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]